# Call a function on a directive from within a function on another directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angular js ionic v1. I'm unable to call a function present in one directive from inside another directive. Below is the code where I'm facing the issue. Let's say directive 1 and directive 2 each have their own HTML and CSS.

```
$scope.closeFunction = function(){
    $scope.closeFunction.hide();
};
```

I want to use the above function inside of a function in another directive. ie. On click calls `submit`, and submit calls `closeFunction`. I should be able to call that.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.closeFunction();
}
```

Comment: No real content changes, though tried to make the 'some function' and 'some other' function a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options, let's say both directives are nested. Then you can pass the function as a parameter.

```
<parent>
  <child close="closeFunction()"><child>
</parent>
```

In your child directive,

```
scope: {
  close: '&'
},
controller: ($scope) => {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.close();
  }
}
```

Or use the `require` property, (**child component**)

```
require: '^parent',
link: (scope, el, attrs, $ctrlParent) => {
  scope.submit = function() {
    $ctrlParent.closeFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I used a different approach and it worked , Used broadcast to controller from parent directive and used & to bring that back to directive.